# a formula to look in an array for a date range and return left most value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, lookup, date-range

Is there a formula that exists that can look between 2 dates in a table and return the Value in the left most cell.

This is the table array that holds the date range.

```
       A             B               C           D        E       
1  Catergory    Start Date  End Date             Date   
2  A            01/01/1500  30/04/1938          
3  B            01/05/1938  31/03/1963          
4  C            01/04/1963  30/12/1988          
5  D            01/01/1989  31/03/1994          
6  F            01/04/1994  29/12/1995          
7  Year Files   30/12/1995  13/07/2008
```

What I want to happen is someone enters any date in cell E1 (example) is looks in the above table and if its between any of the above dates it returns the relevant category.

Comment: You have gaps in your dates. Is that intentional? What response do you want from this formula when someone inputs a date that falls in those gaps?

Comment: Find a case where the preferred date is `<=C` and `>=B` and use that row to index the value in `A`

Comment: @JNevill has a point. You might get a data point about the defeat of the Spanish Armada or the founding of Saint Petersburg. 1500-1938 leaves a lot of wiggle room!

Comment: thanks for responding all, the date 01/01/1500 was just a safe date for me to put in a box, anything prior to 30/04/1938 i want to return Category A, the Gaps are intentional as there would be no work completed within those gaps, if that makes sense?

Comment: also just to add that im using Excel online so VBA is out of the question unfortunately and will have to be a formula.

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 I was more concerned about dates like `04/01/1994`. I felt like this would be an easy one to knock out with `match()`, but with the gaps something more CSE, or SumProduct()-like would be more appropriate.

Comment: Sorry J, not taking shots, just trying to be light

Comment: for the purpose i need the gaps in dates wont make a huge difference so i've changed it so all the dates are continuous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work online too:

```
=IFERROR(LOOKUP(2,1/($B$2:$B$7<=E1)/($C$2:$C$7>=E1),$A$2:$A$7),"")
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks for this, ive just tried this and if i type in a date that is prior to 30/04/1938 the cell remains blank instead of Category A

Comment: nevermind, i change cell B 2 to 0 and it works perfectly! cheers mate.